# Continuity of an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in L^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $Z = (z_1,z_2,\dots,z_k)$ denote a k-tuple where each $z_i \in \Omega$

Consider $$F(Z) = \int_\Omega f(y)\min_{1\leq i \leq k}|y-z_i|^2dy$$

Then, I want to show that $F(Z)$ is continuous as a function which maps $\Omega^k$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

My intuition is that $\min_{1\leq i \leq k}|y-z_i|^2$ does not change drastically with $z_i$, so the whole integral $F$ should be continuous, but I want to prove the continuity of $F(Z)$ rigorously.

How should I prove this?

Comment: Did you intend to have an $f$ rather than a $\rho$ in the integrand?

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ and $h$ are bounded continuous functions on $\Omega$ one has
$$\left|\int_\Omega fg\>dy -\int_\Omega fh\>dy\right|\leq \int_\Omega|f|\>|g-h|\>dy\leq \|f\|_1\>\|g-h\|_\infty\ \ .\tag{1}$$
Assume now that $|z_i-z_i'|\leq\epsilon$ $\>(1\leq i\leq m)$, and put
$$g(y):=\min_i|y-z_i|^2,\qquad h(y):=\min_i|y-z_i'|^2\ .$$
We then have
$$\sqrt{g(y)}\leq|y-z_i|\leq |y-z_i'|+\epsilon\qquad\forall i$$
and therefore
$$\sqrt{g(y)}\leq \sqrt{h(y)}+\epsilon\qquad(y\in\Omega) \ .$$
By symmetry, we also have $\sqrt{h(y)}\leq \sqrt{g(y)}+\epsilon$. This implies
$$\bigl|g(y)-h(y)\bigr|=\left|\sqrt{g(y)}+\sqrt{h(y)}\right|\ \left|\sqrt{g(y)}-\sqrt{h(y)}\right|\leq 2D\epsilon\qquad(y\in\Omega)\ ,$$
where $D:={\rm diam}(\Omega)$.

From $(1)$ we therefore obtain
$$\bigl|F(Z)-F(Z')\bigr|\leq 2\|f\|_1\>D\>\epsilon\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

I will prove this in two parts.  In (1), I will assume that 
$$g(y, Z) \, := \min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \,|y-z_i|^2$$
is uniformly continuous on $\Omega \times \Omega^k$ and use this assumption to prove that $F$ is continuous.  In (2), I’ll prove that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega \times \Omega$.

(1) Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $Z \in \Omega^k$.  We must show that there exists $\delta > 0$ so that if $\delta \geq |W-Z\,| := \left(\sum_{i=1}^k |w_i - z_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$, then
$|F(W) - F(Z)| \leq \varepsilon$.  We assume that $||f||_{L_1(\Omega)} \neq 0$; otherwise $F$ is identically $0$.  Then since $g$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that if $|(y_1,Z_1) -(y_2, Z_2)| \leq \delta$, then $$|g(y_1, Z_1) - g(y_2, Z_2)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{||f||_1}.$$
Let $|W - Z\,| \leq \delta$.  Then by the triangle inequality for integrals, we have
$$|F(W) - F(Z)| \,  \leq \, \int_{\Omega} \left|\,f(y)\min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \,|y-z_i|^2 \right| \, dy \, \leq  \frac{\varepsilon}{||f||_1} \int_{\Omega} |f(y)| \, dy \, = \, \varepsilon.$$

(2) Since $\Omega$ is bounded, choose $R > 0$ so that $\Omega \subset B(0,R)$.  It suffices to prove that $g$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline{B} \times \overline{B}^{\,n}$.  For this, fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $(y_0, Z\,) \in \overline{B} \times \overline{B}^{\,n}$. We must show that there exists $ \delta > 0$ so that if $|(y_1,W) -(y_0, Z)| \leq \delta$, then $$|g(y_1, W) - g(y_0, Z)| \leq \varepsilon.$$
Choose $j$ so that $$|y_0 - z_j|^2 = \min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \,|y_0-z_i|^2.$$  It may be the case that there is more than one coordinate that attains the minimum; to deal with this contingency, suppose that $I \subset \{1,…,k\}$ is the set of indices $i$ so that $$|y_0 - z_i|^2 = \min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \,|y_0-z_i|^2,$$ i.e. the set of indices $i$ so that $z_i = z_j$.  It must be the case that if $i \notin I$, then $|y_0-z_i|^2 > |y_0-z_j|^2$.  By continuity of norm squared, we can choose $\delta_0 > 0$ so that if $|(y_1, W) - (y_0, Z)| \leq \delta_0$, then for any $i \in I$ and $\ell \notin I$, we have 
$$
|y_1-w_{\ell}|^2 > |y_1 - w_i|^2.  
$$

Define $h:\Omega \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$h(y,z) = |y-z|^2.$$
Since h is continuous (in particular, continuous at $(y_0,z_j)$), there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ so that if 
$|(y,w)-(y_0,z_j)| \leq \delta_1$, then $|h(y,w) - h(y_0,z_j)| \leq \varepsilon$.  If $|(y_1,W)-(y_0,Z)| \leq \delta_{1}$, then any $i \in I$ satisfies $|(y_1,w_i) -(y_0,z_j)|\leq \delta_{1}$.  Consequently, for any $i \in I$,
$$\left| |y_1 - w_i|^2 - |y_0 - z_j|^2 \right| \leq \varepsilon. \, \, \, \, (\dagger)$$  Assuming moreover that $|(y_1,W)-(y_0,Z)| \leq \delta_{0}$, 
$$\min_{1 \leq i \leq k} \,|y_1-w_i|^2$$ cannot be attained for an $i \notin I$, so $(\dagger)$
implies that 
$$|g(y_1,W)-g(y_0,Z)| \leq \varepsilon.$$ Thus, we can take $\delta = \min\{\delta_0, \delta_1\}$.